# presentViewController not showing tabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iPhone application that uses a tabbar on all my views.
Also, my first view controller has no navigationBarController but my second view does, as well as the tabbar.

My second view controller is a tableview and when I click on one of the cells, I want to be taken to the first view controller (passing along a parameter with it).

I've tried a few ways of doing with, which all kinda work, but don't.

```
secondViewController.m
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[firstViewController passThisAlong:@"id"];

//[self presentViewController:firstViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; //1
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:YES]; //2
//[self.tabBarController presentViewController:firstViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; //3
[firstViewController release];
firstViewController = nil;
```

So as you can see above, I've tried 3 different methods of getting to the first view controller.
The second one loads the first view, drilled down inside the second view, as it keeps the nagigationBarController (even though first view doesn't have one) with the back button to the second view.

The other two do the same thing as each other. Which is it goes to the first view (without a navigationBar), but, there is no tabbar and the content of the first view has been shifted up about the height of the tabbar, and in it's place is just blackness.

I hope this all makes sense. I just want to be able to go from my second view when someone selects a cell in the table, to my first view as if I'd clicked the icons in the tabbar.

I've seen in the docs
`'On iPhone and iPod touch, the presented view is always full screen. On iPad, the presentation depends on the value in the modalPresentationStyle property.'` not sure if this is related to my issue and if so, if there's a way around it.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal, a modal View is supposed to work this way

From [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

> The ability to present view controllers is a tool that you have at your disposal for interrupting the current workflow and displaying a new set of views. Most commonly, an app presents a view controller as a temporary interruption in order to obtain key information from the user. However, you can also use presented view controllers to implement alternate interfaces for your app at specific times.

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can use something like

```
YourAppNameDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppNameDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate tabBarController].selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas, that works well. However, how would I pass my method `[passThisAlong:@"id"]`. Where before it was like `FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[firstViewController passThisAlong:@"id"];` how would I make this work with your example?

Comment: I'd create a property on the first viewController then you can set its property.

Comment: or you can use delegation, I think that would be neat

Comment: I don't suppose you have an example of this? I really don't know how I'd pass my method to the first view controller using your app delegate route. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are really a lot of different ways of doing this. It really depends on how your project is organized. I guess the easiest way would be to create a property on appDelegate let's call it yourProperty. So you'd have to set this new property each time you select a row on your table view and on your viewWillAppear: of the first controller you read it `YourAppNameDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppNameDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`
 you would then access it using `appDelegate.yourProperty;`

Comment: HA, HA! You genius I could kiss you!! That worked a treat. I'm no iOS mastermind so sorry to keep at you, but that worked flawlessly. Thank you muchly for that, and for your prompt replies!

Answer (score 1):

*Present modal view works this way. And why can't you use a Tab based application?*

Comment: Just tried and like the others, If I do `[self presentModalViewController:smartPicViewController animated:YES];` it doesn't show the tabbar

Comment: Present modal view will make use of entire screen. You could go for Tab + Navigation based application :-)